# How can I increment the id in jquery with for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 'for loop' and I want to send the values through jquery but I can't increment the value of id, 'my_id' is the id of my input fields.

```
for(i=0;i<6;i++){
    $("#my_id_+i").val('test');
}
```

Comment: `$("#my_id_" + i).val('test');`

Comment: @Soft Technoes, It's always better if you post entire blocks related to the question. In your case that would be the DOM section that you want to update and js part. In that way you can get better answer. For instance, if your code like <div id='my_id_1'></div><div id='my_id_2'></div><div id='my_id_3'></div>. The easiest way to update them all would be to add a single class across all divs, so you can update their value with one line of code. $(".classname").val("test"). But if you have n number of divs, probably for loop is the way to go.

Comment: If you have for loop and you're using jQuery. Why not use the jquery.each like the following: 

$('[id*="my_id_"]').each(function(indx){
    // your code
 console.log($(this));
      // to set a value
      $(this).val('test');
})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` has dynamic value but your code treat that as a string.

Try

```
$("#my_id_"+i).val('test');
```

Answer (score 3):

With ES6 you can use `let` to properly scope variable to the loop and string interpolation to make the code cleaner:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  $(`#my_id_${i}`).val('test');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a template string to reference a variable from within a string literal:

```
for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    $(`#my_id_${i}`).val('test');
}
```

You can also use `+` but with the `+ i` out of the string literal:

```
for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    $("#my_id_" + i).val('test');
}
```

If you don't have more `6` elements whose `id` starts with `my_id_`, you can avoid a loop and use:

```
$('[id^="my_id_"]').val('test');
```

Comment: I found the solution... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

you are putting `i` inside double quote hence it is part of string and not getting evaluated as variable. keep it outside and it will work

```
for(i=0;i<6;i++){
    $("#my_id_" +i).val('test');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the +i outside of the String

```
for(i=0;i<6;i++){
    $("#my_id_"+i).val('test');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for this purpose you can combine string with `i` that you get from for each loop:

```
for(i=0;i<6;i++){
    $("#my_id_"+i).val('test');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$("#my_id_+i").val('test'); and maybe it would be better to declare the counter with let declaration

```
for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    $("#my_id_" + i).val('test');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I found the solution. This part is working fine..

```
for(i=0;i<6;i++){
    $("#my_id_"+i).val('test');
}
```

Comment: This is redundant, there's a lot of answers (also redundant) already with this approach. Just accept one of them instead of just repeating what they say.